# How to add value to an array that matches the previous value

Tags: java, arrays

I have a pretty simple problem that I'm trying to solve but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it. If I had an array that consisted of `[1,3,2,7]` and after running the method would return `[1,1,3,3,2,2,7,7]` what would be the best way to do that? I also have a size variable that can increase the size of the array to make room, for example, after doing **`size*2`** I would get `[1,3,2,7,0,0,0,0]`

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java cannot grow or shrink. So, given that your 'output' is differently sized from your 'input', there's only one way: Make a new array.

For #1:

- Make a new array that is `input.length * 2` in size.
- loop through each item in the input with a `for (int = 0; i < ...)` style loop, as you need the index.
- Figure out how to 'map' 0 into `out[0]` and `out[1]`, 1 onto `out[2]` and `out[3]`, 2 onto `out[4]` and `out[5]`, etcetera. It's a trivial math exercise.

For the second, it's even easier. Or, just use `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` which does exactly what you described.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to solve this, I would use the following approch:

- Create a new Array of length **`Size * 2`**,
- Now, traverse from `for (int i = len; i > 0;...)`, and for each `i` I will do the following

```
nums1[(i * 2) - 1] = nums[i - 1];
nums1[(i * 2) - 2] = nums[i - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Create a result array of double size and populate it by copying the elements from the input:

```java
public static int[] duplicateArray(int ... arr) {
    int[] res = new int[2 * arr.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (int x : arr) {
        res[i++] = res[i++] = x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

2. Use `Arrays.copyOf` to create a copy of the input array padded with zeroes.
   Fill the result array in reverse direction (from the last to the first):

```java
public static int[] duplicateArrayCopy(int ... arr) {
    int[] res = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 2 * arr.length); // res is padded with 0s
    for (int i = res.length - 1, j = arr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        res[i--] = res[i--] = res[j];
    }
    return res;
}
```

3. Use Stream API, mainly `flatMap` operation
   However, many intermediate objects (arrays or streams) are created in this approach.

```java
public static int[] duplicateArrayStream(int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr) // IntStream
                 .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(new int[]{x, x}))
                 .toArray();
               
}
// or
public static int[] duplicateArrayStream2(int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x, x).mapToInt(i -> i))
                 .toArray();
}
```